# Change Solr shema before DIH

Tags: solr, solrj, dih

I try to change Solr schema before DIH to fit it to SQL query result. I use my custom proccesor and in init method i add new fields in schema:

```
@Override
public void init(Context context) {
    super.init(context);
    String mode = (String) context.getRequestParameters().get("command");
    if (mode.equals("full-import")) {
        Map<String, Object> row = this.nextRow();
        Set<String> fields = context.getSolrCore().getLatestSchema().getFields().keySet();
        IndexSchema schema = context.getSolrCore().getLatestSchema();

        Map<String, Object> fieldAttributes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        fieldAttributes.put("stored", true);
        fieldAttributes.put("indexed", true);

        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : row.entrySet()) {
            if (!fields.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                SchemaField schemaField = schema.newField(entry.getKey(), "string", fieldAttributes);
                schema = schema.addField(schemaField);
            }
        }

        context.getSolrCore().setLatestSchema(schema);
    }
    rowIterator = null;
}
```

All works, but import go by old schema (i had only 3 fields at start). I see changes on schema after first import. If i restart import again - all works good, and i see all my new fields with their values.

How to point Solr to the new schema and do not restart import?

**UPDATE:**

I extend SqlEntityProcessor

```
    public class KinefProccessor extends SqlEntityProcessor {
    
        @Override
        public void init(Context context) {
            super.init(context);
            String mode = (String) context.getRequestParameters().get("command");
....
....
```

And my config:

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://*******" user="***" password="***" />
    <document>
        <entity name="item" query="****"  processor = "KinefProccessor">
            <field column="v.id" name="id" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: you have to restart solr after the schema chnages

Comment: No. Just restart import, and i saw changes in managed-schema

Comment: As far as I can tell from the tests invoking `setLatestSchema` should change the schema as an atomic operation, but which class are you extending? When is this part of the code being invoked? It might be that the internal SolrDocument has already been created, and since that's when the content of the schema is being read, that data is now stale.

Comment: i fix my topic. i extend SqlEntityProcessor